# Error in <c:forEach> tag in JSTL while using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jstl, tomcat10

I am learning JSTL and I have downloaded **JSTL 2.0.0** from [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.glassfish.web/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/2.0.0/jar) because **jstl 1.2.2** was using *javax* and I am using *jakarta*.

**display.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:out value="Jai Swaminarayan"/>

    <c:forEach items="${students}" var="s">
        ${s} <br/><br/>
    </c:forEach>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

This code keeps throwing the following error:

*Error on Eclipse*

```
A problem was encountered using TagExtraInfo class 
 org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.ForEachTEI for 'c:forEach'
```

*Error on Webpage*

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report
Message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTag
Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

I have even added *.jar* file to **Build Path** and `WEB-INF` Folder. I do Not think this  issue is with *.jar* file but I could be wrong.

Here, `<c:out>` is working perfectly but it only throws error in `<c:forEach>` tag. I checked the files in **jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0.jar** and file named **forEachTag.class** Does Exists in **org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.ForEachTEI**

---

Software Data:

**Java Version**: 15.0.2 | **Server**: Tomcat-10 | **IDE**: Eclipse

---

**What I tried:**

I cannot find the source but some answer asked to remove whitespace between `<%@` and `taglib`

`<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

Trying since long time. Any help is appreciable :)

Comment: Looks like you're missing the "jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api" Dependency as listed in the lower right of the linked page.

Comment: @nitind I downloaded all four Dependencies:

    `jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api jakarta.servlet.jsp:jakarta.servlet.jsp-api jakarta.el:jakarta.el-api jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api`, but it is yet not working

Comment: All of the other dependencies come as part of Tomcat. Duplicates would only give you new problems.

Comment: EDIT : I mean I tried it with all 4 dependencies and also with this only one`jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api` dependency. But its not working

Comment: Jars should go in the WEB-INF/**lib** folder for the server to use them at runtime.

Comment: Yes, it is in **lib** folder. https://ibb.co/RHxMyWX

Comment: [This](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet.jsp/jakarta.servlet.jsp-api/3.0.0) link also shows to write dependency. How should I write it and where should I write it?. I am new to this. I am Not using Maven. I am using Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse

Comment: Those only apply to those using those build tools (Maven, Gradle, etc.), which don't apply to you, then. Check the server log for an extended stack trace.

Comment: Open the _"Deployment Assembly"_ configuration of your project and check whether `src/main/webapp` is deployed (to `/`).

Comment: Odd, the mentioned LoopTag class is in the `jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-2.0.0.jar`that you've now added (although you don't need to manually add any Jar to the Java Build Path once it's in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder). Try undoing your own added references to the libraries, then go to the Servers view, right-click on the Tomcat server entry, and choose "Clean Tomcat Work Directory". Maybe this is a one-off issue with the deployment being confused by having both jars there twice.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Yes, it is there.

Comment: I restarted my PC and now, `<c:forEach>` is working fine in the browser but still throws a warning in the Eclipse as *A problem was encountered using TagExtraInfo class org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.ForEachTEI for 'c:forEach'*. And yes @nitind, I tried undoing my own added references. But it keeps throwing warning in eclipse. https://ibb.co/GcWJg6p

Comment: Ok, **that** message is because the editor doesn't yet support Jakarta Taglibs. It actually has to interact with them during development, apart from any server issues. That specific message will require a future version to correct.

Comment: `org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.ForEachTEI` is not part of Eclipse's JSTL impl. It's part of Apache's JSTL impl. Get rid of `standard.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, I did like the comment said and looked at dependencies, downloaded and put the one below in the `webapp/Web-inf/lib` folder and it worked after [that](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/2.0.0-RC1).